# Python how count an occurrence of a number in a random list

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python, and am having some trouble with an assignment.

The problem asks: How many occurrences of the number 9 appear in our randomly made list?

I need to figure out how to properly add this as a function with while and if statements only.

```
random_list = []
list_length = 20

number = 0
while number < list_length:
    random_list.append(random.randint(0,10))
    number += 1


print random_list
print count
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is `list.count` not allowed? You say you can only use "while and if statements", but I'm not sure what else is allowed, because you're also using assignment statements, in-place-add statements, print statements, list literals, integer literals, binary operators, method calls... You should ask your teacher to be more specific in what is and isn't permitted.

Comment: How would you this without restrictions in a function?

Comment: just `print list.count(9)` in place of `print count`

Comment: Got it so easy. But I will need to clarify the test. The test is setup this way with the teacher using that print statement. I am supposed to put my code underneath the while that is generating the list and the teacher just hits those 2 print statements to get an output.

Comment: use another variable, name it as `count`. Initialize `count = 0` above the while loop (NOT inside). Assign `random.randint(0,10)` to another variable say `rint`. now inside while loop `if rint == 9: count +=1`. That will solve your problem. Although answer is one liner in Python. `import random; print [random.randint(0,10) for x in range(20)].count(9)`

Comment: Thanks you very much Tanmaya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the rules for this assignment, you could use the following. The change is in the middle of the while loop, you check the value of the randomly generated `int`. If it is equal to 9, you add to the count.

```
random_list = []
list_length = 20

count = 0
number = 0

while number < list_length:
    #Generate a random number and assign it to randInt
    randInt = random.randint(0,10)

    #Append the number you just generated to the list
    random_list.append(randInt)
    number += 1


def countNines(list):
    count = 0

    #If the number is 9, add to the count
    for num in list:
        if num == 9:
            count += 1

    return count

count = countNines(random_list)

print random_list
print count
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to add another function underneath the list generator code?

Comment: Under this code to find the occurance 
    number = 0
    while number < list_length:
        random_list.append(random.randint(0,10))
        number += 1

Code Here

Comment: Okay, I added it. I can also remove it form being a function if that's better.

Comment: Wow! Sweet! I was really closed to the answer. I thank you for guidance that really helped a lot to get the understanding I need.